# help in proving equivelant statements of $f=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle f,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i \space \forall f\in H$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ is a hilbert space. $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal set

A set $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is complete in $H$ if any of the following statements hold:

1. $f=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i \space \forall f\in H$
2. $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is an $N<\infty$ such that $\forall n\geq N,  ||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i||<\epsilon$

I wasnt able to prove it. Here is the way I approached the problem:
by 1, we can write
$$||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i||=0$$
$$||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i-\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i||=0$$
$$||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i-\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty  \langle f,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i||=0\geq ||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i||-||\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty  \langle f,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i||$$
$$||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i||\leq||\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty  \langle f,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i||$$

but this way is not taking me anywhere. Any hints will be appreciated

Edit:
I think this is the solution. 
by statement 1:
$$f=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle f, \phi_i \rangle\phi_i$$
$$f=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f, \phi_i \rangle\phi_i$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f, \phi_i \rangle\phi_i)=0$$
Hence, $$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N s. t. ||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \langle f, \phi_i \rangle\phi_i)||\leq\epsilon $$

Comment: I have edited my question. My question is how to show that statement 1 and 2 are equivalent. The way I started the proof didnt taken me anywhere.

Comment: The question as stated is not to show that 1, 2 are equivalent. You are to show that either 1 or 2 would imply that $\phi_i$ is a complete orthonormal set.

Comment: but isn't statement 1 the definition of complete orthonormal set. so I am taking 1 as a given and trying to show statement 2

Comment: In the statement **2**, I think it is $$\forall n\geq N,  ||f-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \langle f,\phi_i \rangle\phi_i||<\epsilon.$$ Which is what you are trying to prove in your attemp :-).

Comment: You have only shown that (1) implies (2). But you still did not shown that $\{\phi_i\}$ is complete.